# Price elasticity of demand

Tags: microeconomics

How does one calculate a firm's price elasticity of demand using the demand curve and only having the current price and the units sold per day?

Comment: Do you have an equation for the demand curve or just a single data point?

Comment: Hi, I have an equation for the demand curve

Answer (score 1):

Based on the available information, you probably have to use the formula for point elasticity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the demand function (i.e., your equation for the demand curve) $Q=D(p)$. Then, the price elasticity of demand is
$$\varepsilon = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} \frac{p}{Q} = \frac{p D'(p)}{D(p)}$$

Suppose you know that at price $p_0$, the quantity demanded $Q_0=D(p_0)$. Then, the elasticity of demand at price $p_0$ is
$$\varepsilon = \frac{p_0 D'(p_0)}{D(p_0)}.$$

**Examples**

1. Suppose $Q=D(p)=a - b \cdot p$. Then, $$\varepsilon=-\frac{bp}{a - b \cdot p}$$.
2. Suppose $Q=D(p)= a \cdot p^{-\epsilon}$. Then, $D'(p) = -a\cdot\epsilon \cdot p^{-(\epsilon+1)}$, and thus,

$$\varepsilon = \frac{p D'(p)}{D(p)} = -\frac{p \cdot a \cdot \epsilon \cdot p^{-(\epsilon+1)}}{a \cdot p^{-\epsilon}} = -\epsilon$$